# Why can not I set a variable dynamically?

Tags: jquery

How can i run this code? `var rating` is always `0`. Only if i set `value=''` directly to `hot-bar-val-c` js working...

HTML:

```
<div class="hot-bar-val"></div>
<input class="hot-bar-val-c" style="display:none;"/>
```

JS

```
$(".hot-bar-val-c").load("../8907654/rating.txt")
var rating = $(".hot-bar-val-c").val();
$(".hot-bar-val").width(rating + "%");
```

EDIT:
rating.txt has this text:

```
50
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Share the folder structure if possible.. of the js file and the txt file..

Comment: folder is ok. When i change html to <input class="hot-bar-val-c" style="display:none;" value="50"/> all works fine.

Comment: You cannot do that. `.hot-bar-val-c` is not a container element and even if it was, by the time you're trying to read the value, the ajax call has not finished. **Ajax call are asynchronous**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see my comment.

```
$.get("../8907654/rating.txt", function(data) {
    var rating = data.trim();
    $(".hot-bar-val-c").val( rating );//if necessary
    $(".hot-bar-val").width( rating + "%" );
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Now i can see that I worked with the unfinished ajax call, and how to do it right

Answer (score 0):

As per the jQuery api for load, you cannot use load over input. jQuery uses javascript's innerHtml property to set the value. You need to set it to a div.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/load/